# Laravel sub app folder structure

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have been going back and forth on this subject and could really use some insight.

I am writing an API in Laravel and an Web App in Laravel. I have been going back and forth in this process wondering if they should be in the same Laravel install or if they should be in separate installs. The pro's and con's I can think of for separate installs are as follows:

Pro's

1. api code doesn't interfere with web code
2. would use API for
       data fetching and updating -> might be good for future scaling

Con's

1. Multiple laravel installations
2. Unable to use Eloquent (would save a
   lot of work) -> since data would come from api.

What is the best way to do this?

Also, the real question is, if I were to keep them on the same installation, what is the best way to set up the folder structure to essentially run to apps on a single Laravel installation?

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the code with namespaces. Use the composer.json file and PSR-4 so you can have separate code bases, even controller and models. Or you can use the same models in the Core namespace.

```
{
  ...
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "Api\\": "app/Api",
          "Core\\": "app/Core",
          "Web\\": "app/Web"
    },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I have seen that "PSR-4" and "PSR-0" stuff all over the place and really have no idea what it is all about. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you would want to keep the models together at least?

I recommend keeping the installs together and separating using routes:

```
Route::group( array('before'=>array('api'), 'prefix' => 'api' ), function() {
    ...
}

Route::group( array('before'=>array('auth'), 'prefix' => 'webapp' ), function() {
    ...
}
```

Structure is personal preference but I would have:

```
Controllers
      |------API
      |       |-------MyController.php
      |
      |------WebApp
              |-------MyController.php
```

And then in the controller use namespaces:

```
<?php
namespace API;

class MyController extends \APIBaseController {
```

Update:

If you want namespaces throughout then do this:

```
     app
      |
      |------core
      |       |-------Models
      |
      |------api
      |       |-------Controllers
      |
      |------webapp
              |-------Controllers
```

Comment: Ok but then how would you set up the folder structure?

Comment: That's down to personal preference but I would have:

Comment: Why APIBaseController and AppBaseController? They can't both extend \BaseController?

Comment: APIBaseController and AppBaseController will both extend \BaseController so that you can put specific methods for the API in the API one etc.